# Branching in CIL

Tags: .net, cil

I have a question about CIL. What is the `beq` (Branch to target if equal) command in CIL for?

I've read about it here: [List of CIL instructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CIL_instructions)

Comment: Are you saying you fully understand every other instruction *except* `beq`? If so, what about it do you find confusing/not in keeping with the other instructions? Or are we to expect a flood of questions, each one about a single instruction?

Comment: The rest seems to be pretty clear, but i do not understand the branching concept.

Comment: Ok, i understand, `beq` jumps to a branch (for exampple: `beq       IL_0011 ---> IL_0011:  ldloc.1`) if the compared value is true. Is that correct?

Comment: The name explains it all beq : Branch to target if equal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `beq target` instruction transfers control ("jumps") to target if top two values on the stack are equal. This is the same as a `ceq` instruction followed by a `brtrue target`. Given method:

```
static int BranchTest(int value1, int value2)
{
    if (value1 == value2)
    {
        return SomeMethod(0);
    }
    else
    {
        return SomeMethod(1);    
    }
}
```

it can be (but this is only an examplatory code) translated into:

```
.method private hidebysig static 
    int32 BranchTest (
        int32 value1,
        int32 value2
    ) cil managed 
{
    // ...

    IL_0000: ldarg.0      // load value1 on stack
    IL_0001: ldarg.1      // load value2 on stack
    IL_0002: beq IL_000b  // compare and jump conditionaly

    IL_0004: ldc.i4.1
    IL_0005: call int32 ConsoleLeak.Program::SomeMethod(int32)
    IL_000a: ret

    IL_000b: ldc.i4.0
    IL_000c: call int32 ConsoleLeak.Program::SomeMethod(int32)
    IL_0011: ret
}
```